# Unable to read parameters from GAS web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I am organising an event where each attendee has a unique barcoded ticket. The barcode is a **QR code** linking to a GAS web app with url parameters for lookup in a private spreadsheet (name, ticket code and attendance date). Lets call the parameters `a`, `b` and `c`

The problem I have is that my `doGet(e)` function is not finding the parameters in the url and so all spreadsheet checks are failing, even if the data is in the sheet. The relevant code I have is as follows:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

  var name = e.parameter.a[0];
  var ticketID = e.parameter.b[0];
  var attendanceDate = e.parameter.c[0];

  // other code

  var attendeeNames = sheet.getRange("A:A1").getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < attendeeNames.length; i++) {
    if (attendeeNames[i] == name) {
      // ticket ID and date checks go here but name is failing
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*`e.parameter` should be replaced with `e.parameters`.*

#### Explanation:

There are two ways of obtaining parameters from event objects in Apps Script Web Apps - `e.parameter` and `e.parameters`. As per the documentation:

**e.parameter:**

> An object of key/value pairs that correspond to the request parameters. Only the first value is returned for parameters that have multiple values.

```
{"name": "alice", "n": "1"}
```

**e.parameters:**

> An object similar to e.parameter, but with an array of values for each key

```
{"name": ["alice"], "n": ["1", "2"]}
```

Only `e.parameters` uses arrays for the values of the key-value pairs and so when you're calling the values with

```js
var name = e.parameter.a[0];
var ticketID = e.parameter.b[0];
var attendanceDate = e.parameter.c[0];
```

You will be returning null.

#### Fixes:

There are a couple of other issues that will need to be fixed with your code. In order to get the range of a column, you need to use `.getRange('A1:A')`, and not `.getRange('A:A1;)`.

Replace:

```js
var name = e.parameter.a[0];
var ticketID = e.parameter.b[0];
var attendanceDate = e.parameter.c[0];
```

with:

```js
var name = e.parameters.a[0];
var ticketID = e.parameters.b[0];
var attendanceDate = e.parameters.c[0];
```

Or, if you only have one parameter for `a`, `b` and `c`, you can just use:

```js
var name = e.parameter.a;
var ticketID = e.parameter.b;
var attendanceDate = e.parameter.c;
```

Also, replace:

```js
var attendeeNames = sheet.getRange("A:A1").getValues();
```

with:

```js
var attendeeNames = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
```

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script Web Apps Request Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)
- [Google Sheets API v4 A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation)